# In what ways can I get coins in Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

Coins are the de facto currency in Overwatch and can be used to purchase pretty much any Hero's cosmetics, including skins, sprays, and victory poses.

What methods are available to get coins, and which ways are more efficient?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get coins two ways, both are from Loot Boxes.

The first is actual coin drops:

- Common - 15 coins
- Rare - 50 coins
- Epic - 150 coins
- Legendary - 500 coins

You also get coins if you get a Duplicate item.

- Common - 5 coins
- Rare - 15 coins
- Epic - 50 coins
- Legendary - 200 coins

Having said that, Blizzard will hopefully add another way to get these as it costs quite a bit to get Legendary items... 1000 coins each.

Comment: Having said that, it was disappointed to open a chest, see I got a Epic item and see it was just 150 coins.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot to mention that I found it in Common and Epic chests, so I just assumed Rare was 100 since the others were 50 and 150.

Comment: I believe Legendary coin drops only net you 1k or 250, forget which one

Comment: Apparently the amount you get for duplicates changes by level too... I'll have to update it.

Comment: Can confirm I've had all three types of coin drops you mentioned and the respective amounts are correct.

Comment: You can get legendary drop for coins. I got a legendary drop once and thought it was a skin, but when the disc thingy landed it was actually 500 coins. Sadly I didnt take a picture.

Comment: Oh yeah, I should have updated this as I'd gotten 500 coins from a Legendary coin drop towards the end of the Open Beta. For that matter, I'm pretty sure I had the common and rare amounts wrong.

Comment: @Powerlord Could you update this along with the proper coin amounts for duplicates as well? Thanks!

Comment: @O-O I already did.  I suppose I could add the parts about duplicates too.  I think it's always 20% of their buy cost (5, 15, 50, 500).

Comment: There, I've updated the post to have better formatting.

Comment: (The 500 coins from my comment two up was a braino, it's 200 coins)